# Microsoft Access 2010 update query - updating foreign key field

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, foreign-keys, ms-access-2010

I have the following 2 tables and im trying to update the CategoryID foreign key field in the subcategories table. One category can have multiple subcategories, so the relationship here is one to many.

Im trying to do this in the query design view.The criteria im trying to use for the update is as follows:

Category names start with a number eg 106 Packing material. Subcategories for this category will start with the same three digits eg 106 cardboard, 106 bubblewrap etc.

As i have a long list of subcategories, im trying to use an update query, to enter the category ID (Categories.ID) into the categoryID column in the subcategories table (subcategories.CategoryID) where the first 3 digits are the same.

So in the example above,if 106 packaging material has an ID of 1 in the categories table, then 106 cardboard and 106 bubblewrap will have "1" in their categoryID field.

I know i can use Left(categoryname,3) to extract the numbers to compare but dont know how to construct he update statement to accomplish this, or where to place it.

So my final desired result is that all subcategories have a corresponding CategoryID entry. Some more category and related subcategory examples are:

- 101 stationery (ID 2)-> 101 notebooks, 101 Pens, 101 writing pads
- 102 Art and craft (ID 3) -> 102 paints, 102 brushes

Id appreciate some help and im quite new to SQL and access.

thanks

[image: Tables and their relationship]

UPDATE:

i tried the following sql

`UPDATE subCategories INNER JOIN categories ON subCategories.categoryID = categories.ID SET subCategories.CategoryID = [Categories].[ID]
WHERE ((Left([Categories].[Category],3)=Left([Subcategories].[Subcategory],3)));`

Here is the same query in design view:

[image: query design]

But this is the result it returns:

[image: Query result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

UPDATE categories, subCategories SET subCategories.CategoryID = [categories].[ID]
WHERE ((Left([Categories].[Category],3)=Left([Subcategories].[Subcategory],3)));

In order for this to work properly, you need to make sure that the three numbers in Category are unique. If there are multiple occurences of the same number, this update will not work properly.

Comment: hi, i tried this but keep getting syntax errors? should this sql work on an access database? a colleague thinks it looks like sql server syntax. sorry but im very new to all this !

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited the answer to work with access.